# Visual Studio gets filled with black color forcing restart

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Visual studio 2010 gets filled with black color wherever the mouse moves and restarting VS is the only option to get out of it.Has anyone encountered this problem ? This occurs at random and this irritating bug is quite frequent for me.

Any help to fix this will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to Tools->Options->Environment->General and unchecking "Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance" and then uncheck "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available.

This feature has been known to cause some issues with the rendering of the application and might provide a resolution for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Quintin. After I did this, this issue didn't occur till now.